# Retrieve a page's XML for Python parsing

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a Python script implementing BeautifulSoup that parses an XML file in the same directory. There are a lot of pages on a site that I want to parse with the exact same XML format. I want to feed the script a url at which it can get the page's XML and parse it, rather than downloading each XML and changing the `xml_file` in the raw code. Here's what my code entails. I am trying to replace `xml_file="somefileID.xml"` with a script that gets the page's xml.

```
#The program just goes through and pulls info from different tags.

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml_file="somefileID.xml" #get this ID from the page using a script somehow??
#Then somehow put that id you got into "http://someurl.com/"+xml_file 
xml_string = open(xml_file).read() #go on to read your new xml file

#Status
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string)
status = soup.find('some-tag')['some-attribute']
print "\nSome Prompt: "+attribute+"\n"
print "Most Recent Event Information: \n"

#Most Recent Event Date
event_date = lambda x: x.name == "date"

events = soup.findAll(event_date)
if(events):
    # The last event-data
    print "Date: "+events[-2].text

print "Analysis Complete."
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Are you starting with an XML document that has references to other documents, and you want to parse the first one, and fetch and parse all the linked documents? If so, that's basically the same as HTML scraping, so you may want to look at a scraping library. But for simple-enough cases, it's easy to write it yourself.

Comment: No the XML document does not have references. Here's my context: i am provided an excel sheet with page ID's (for example: EP0972029, EP0972114, EP0974655, and so on) which correspond to page url's (http://site.com/EP0972029... and so on). I need to, instead of *download* those XML's, view the XML of the page, and bring the info  into the script that way. I don't want to download thousands of pages but instead have the script view the XML's of the pages and parse them. The pages as of now are in HTML formate and only give me the option to download the XML. There's gotta be someway i canview it

Comment: What do you mean by "view"? You mean you just want to download them into memory or temporary files, process them, and throw them away, so you only have one at a time sitting around instead of thousands of them? If so, that's easy—in fact, it's just ToxicTeacakes' one-liner. That `xml_file` isn't an actual file on disk, it's entirely in memory, but you can still `read()` from it just as if it _were_ a file.

Comment: So if I have a URL to the XML download, i can just do: `xml_file= urllib.urlopen("http://site.com/xml-download")` ?

Comment: in other words does that download exist in text anywhere on that site? even though it has a download? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** As with any internet page, you cannot merely "view" an xml file. When you load a page, you download it.

```
import urllib
xml_file= urllib.urlopen("somefileID.xml")
```

will do this.

**EDIT 2:**
You are correct in saying that `xml_file= urllib.urlopen("http://site.com/xml-download")` will retrieve the xml. That url is the link to the text stored on the website. However, to access that text you must download it first.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately I lack sufficient reputation to comment on a question, but still wanted to contribute. Will delete upon response from asker.